# how do I handle matching query does not exist when try catch doesnt work?

Tags: python, django

I want to skip adding subtechnique if the parent technique is not on the database to avoid `matching query does not exist.` , but however if I use `.first or .exists` it doesnt work even with `if not ...` or try catch blocks keeps the same error where come from `Dmeo.objects.get_or_create(` how can I fix this issue?

trace back

```
analizer         | apps.api.models.DoesNotExist: Dmeo matching query does not exist.

analizer         | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
analizer         | 
analizer         | Traceback (most recent call last):
analizer         |   File "updater.py", line 38, in <module>
analizer         |     subtechnique, created = Dmeo.objects.get_or_create(
```

falling code

```
for subtechnique in src_subtechniques:
    for data_subtechniques in subtechnique:
        technique = Technique.objects.filter(technique_id=data_subtechniques['technique_id'].partition('.')[0]).exists()
        subtechnique, created = Dmeo.objects.get_or_create(
            subtechnique_id=data_subtechniques['technique_id'],
            technique_name=data_subtechniques['technique'],
            url=data_subtechniques['url'],
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`except (Dmeo.DoesNotExist):`

In case it doesn't, this might do the trick:

`except (models.DoesNotExist):`